# "map-like" interface for HTML with PDF as background

Tags: javascript, google-maps

What I've got:

- PDF map with coordinates of corners (in the real world)
- Dynamic list of coordinates to display as markers

I need to get a map, only consisting of the PDF with a marker for each coordinate that are clickable. The list of coordinates obviously is dynamic, so I can't just draw them on the PDF directly. I must be able to zoom/pan.

I know that I could use Google Maps API (exactly what I did until now) to display the data-points as markers with some callback to display the additional information. However I can't find a way to use the PDF as an overlay without tiling the PDF into rasterized images (MapTiler).

Is there any JS library that would help me achieve my goal?
Or is there a way to do it in Google Maps?

Comment: no js library but some tools  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24146/from-pdf-to-google-maps-overlay

Comment: What are the extents, projection, and any special features of your PDF map?